# SSRS elements jumping of Position

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, preview

I am currently having the following Problem:

I have 2 SSRS Texboxes which I place right above a Matrix:
[image: ElemntJUMP]

Now as you can see the Textboxes are fixed in a standalone Position, and are all alone without anything else around them,
but guess what happens as soon as I click to Preview my Report, this happens:

[image: JumpingAround]

The Textboxes Fly out of the Report,
and I have done everything to get them in place, I have tried getting them a little to the left, but in the end, after I got to where it would stop jumping, I got them so much left that they were in a place that I couldn't have them in.

Has anybody using Reporting Services ever experienced this?

Does anyone have a solution? Are there some properties I need to change in order for the Textboxes to stop Jumping?

Comment: The positioning is not fixed, it is relative. Try placing your controls in rectangles, this should help enforce your desired layout.

Comment: could you better explain ?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great Question, GBerisha! Essentially, you want the horizontal distance between the Heading Textbox and the two rightmost Textboxes to be fixed. There are two ways to accomplish this. The first would be to create a Rectangle from the Toolbox Menu and place the Heading Textbox and the two rightmost Textboxes inside that Rectangle. That will keep the expanding Matrix from pushing out the two rightmost Textboxes as it expands. The other way would be to create a Table, delete the Detail Row, and place the three Textboxes in the Table Header.